# Angular Material Components mat-select and mat-label cropped text

Tags: html, css, components, angular6, angular-material-6

I'am facing the problem that my used font-family is causing text cropping on some material components like **mat-select, mat-label, mat-input**. Is it just an **line-height** css problem? For input I solved it by increasing the line-height. But for mat-label and mat-select I don't get it. Any ideas?

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Recommended font is Roboto. If you change it, consider changing the values of your font or boxing (`font-size`, `padding` ... )

Comment: you can try by adding google material font icon ```<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet">```